# How to split JPanel diagonally

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I'm trying to make a game board with pieces that are split into four sides, with the lines going diagonally, corner to corner. What would be the way to do that using JPanel stuff?

Comment: If you want to paint diagonal lines then you need to do custom painting. Read the section on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for some examples to get you started. You would use the `drawLine(...)` method of the Graphics object to draw two lines from corner to corner.

Comment: @camickr I will look, but with using drawLine(...) could I edit each side separately? Or would that be more custom painting stuff?